# Frame list with Tkinter and python

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

well i want to do a frame list with some info i get from a db what i trying to do is something like

```
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame2 = Frame(frame1)
frame3 = Frame(frame1)

cont=0
for i in range(2):

    #add some widgets to the frames

    frame2.grid(row=0,column = 0)
    frame2.grid(row=1,column = 0)
    frame3.grid(row=cont,column=0)
    cont += 1
```

expecting that frames stack below of the other but they are printing in 
the same place, im actually trying to learn python and english too haha.
hope someone can explain me what im doing wrong or a better way to do this

thanks.

Comment: Do you want frame1, frame2, and frame3 below each other?

Comment: No, the frame2 and frame3 are attached to the frame1 the frame1 and the frame1 is attached to the root, so i want to print  various frame1 one below the other,

im make a draw
[link](http://prntscr.com/6ar15r)

Comment: Ah, I see.  The problem is that you're just re-gridding the same frame over and over again.  You need to actually make multiple frames, then grid them in different rows.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ohh i see, so i could create a list of frames1? if yes i think i would need to make new frames 2 and 3 too for each new frame1

Comment: Yep - that's the idea.  I wrote up something just like that below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make a little data structure to hold your frames, instead of just using names.  The data structure will end up looking like this:

```
[[frame1_1, frame2_1, frame3_1], [frame1_2, frame2_2, frame3_2]]
```

Here's the code to accomplish that:

```
frameGroup = []

for i in range(2):

    frameGroup.append([None, None, None])
    frameGroup[i][0] = Frame(root)
    frameGroup[i][1] = Frame(frameGroup[i][0])
    frameGroup[i][2] = Frame(frameGroup[i][0])

    #add some widgets to the frames

    frameGroup[i][0].grid(row=i, column=0)
    frameGroup[i][1].grid(row=0, column=0)
    frameGroup[i][2].grid(row=1, column=0)
```